# Linux/C: Check for user credentials in Program

Tags: c, linux, pam

I need to secure a section in my application making sure only the owner of the account can change settings. Is there any way to ask for users credentials like on the loginscreen to unlock the page in the application? Is it possible with PAM?

```
#include <security/pam_appl.h> 

#include <security/pam_misc.h> 

#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{
    pam_handle_t *pamh;
    struct pam_conv pamc;

    pamc.conv = &misc_conv;
    pamc.appdata_ptr = NULL;

    pam_start("su", getenv("USER"), &pamc, &pamh);

    if (pam_authenticate (pamh, 0) != PAM_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Nope!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Good job!\n");
    }
    pam_end(pamh, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

I managed to put this together real quick. Is there a way to give pam the credentials myself? I want the passwort to be asked by GTK in a dialog and then pass it along to PAM if possible...

Comment: I think this would defeat the whole purpose of PAM ...

Comment: Is this check supposed to be in case someone has left the machine running the program, and doesn't want anyone to mess with it? If they haven't locked their desktop when they leave the machine, I think they have other things to worry about!

Comment: I develop a remote control software and I want to prevent a user from changing the unattended password. You have to enter your users credentials to set the password...